# Oracle SQL - Select from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables which are exactly the same layout, but have different data (one is current, one is history).

How do I pull information from both tables?

PSUDO SQL:

```
SELECT 
    T.TRANS_QUAN,
    P.PONO, D.ID
FROM 
    TRANSLOG T, (select * from PO, PO_HIST) P, (SELECT * FROM PO_DETAIL, PO_DETAIL_HIST) D
WHERE 
    D.PO_ID = P.ID
    AND T.SOURCE_ID = D.ID
```

When I try to actually run that I get "column ambiguously defined"

Answer (score 3):

You can UNION clause.

Try:

```
SELECT 
        T.TRANS_QUAN,
        P.PONO, D.ID
    FROM 
        TRANSLOG T, 
            (
                SELECT * FROM PO
                UNION
                SELECT * FROM PO_HIST
            ) P,
         (
            SELECT * FROM PO_DETAIL
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM PO_DETAIL_HIST
         ) D
    WHERE 
        D.PO_ID = P.ID
        AND T.SOURCE_ID = D.ID
```

Comment: never use UNION if there is not a good reason, always use UNION ALL if you want to add records

Comment: @Benoit: So isn't the current requirement a good reason? Ofcourse it can be made better using UNION ALL if having same records is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

```
(select * from PO, PO_HIST) P
```

This subquery might make a cross join of tables that share a common column name.

Maybe you want:

```
Select t.trang_quan
     , p.pono
     , d.id
  from translog t
  inner join po_detail d
     on d.id = t.source_id
  cross join po_detail_hist
  inner join po p
     on p.id = d.po_id
  cross join po_hist p2
```

Are you sure you want cross joins?